# How stop interval timer?

Tags: angular, rxjs

How stop interval when you move to another component in Angular 7:

```
public s: Observable<any>;

this.s = interval(5000)
      .pipe(takeWhile(() => this.visitors.length > 0))
      .subscribe(() => {});
```

I tried to stop interval in component destructor:

```
   ngOnDestroy() {
      this.s.unsubscribe();
  }
```

Comment: It's correct, but since `s` is a local variable, I don't see how you could access it from `ngOnDestroy`. It needs to be a property of the component (and be renamed to a decent name): `this.intervalSubscription = ...`.

Comment: I know, I did this as property, but it does not stop

Comment: So the code you tried isn't the code you posted? And we're supposed to explain why some code that you didn't post doesn't work as you expect? Don't do this. Post a complete minimal example that reproduces the problem. Not imaginary code that you didn't actually use.

Comment: Okay, I did some explanations in question with full code

Comment: This code wouldn't compile. subscribe() doesn't return an Observable. And Observable doesn't have an ùnsubscribe() function. This is imaginary code. Post a complete minimal example that compiles and reproduces the problem.

Comment: That is all, what I have

Comment: Then look at your terminal: it must have red lines indicating compilation errors. Don't try to run the code until you've fixed all those compilation errors.

Comment: You know it is a little bit inconvenient to use a new Rxjs, cause in last version it was more obviously to stop timer or interval

Comment: Rxjs might seem a little more *convenient* if you took the time to learn the tool before starting to use it. There is no shortage of [documentation](https://rxjs.dev/guide/overview).

Comment: Interval Creates an Observable that emits. So, why if it is Observable, I can not stop it using unsubscribe? There is not any information how to stop it: `https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/interval`

Comment: I dont have any errors, that why I posted this question

Comment: Property unsubscribe(); does not exist in `private s: Observable<number>;`

Comment: As mentioned by @JBNizet, "subscribe() doesn't return an Observable", it does return a subscription, so the type of s should be Subscription. Everything else seems fine.

Comment: What is type then?

Comment: `import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';` - `public s: Subscription`

Comment: Thank you, so it does not stop: `ngOnDestroy() {
    this.s.unsubscribe();
  }` no errors

Comment: So you should update your question accordingly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You made 2 mistakes; let me describe them:

- Calling `subscribe()` function doesn't return `Observable`; `pipe`returns.
- Using `unsubscribe` won't stop the interval.

I Use `setInterval` instead of interval like:

```
timer: any;

ngOnInit() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        // here do whatever you want every 5 seconds
    }, 5000);
}
```

And use `clearInterval` function onDestroy; like:

```
ngOnDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.timer);
}
```